# Animate Images with completion handler in Swift

Tags: swift, animation, uikit

Animation is working, however completion handler does not seem to be recognizing the end of the animation. I would like to call that println after the animation has completed. How can I best achieve that?

```
var vaultClosedImage = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "vaultClosedAlpha.png"))
override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool) {
    if flag {
        println("here I am")
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let vaultImages:[AnyObject] = [UIImage(named: "vaultOpening0001.png")!, ...]
    vaultClosedImage.animationImages = vaultImages
    vaultClosedImage.animationRepeatCount = 1
    vaultClosedImage.animationDuration = 1

    vaultClosedImage.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    vaultClosedImage.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectToFill
    self.view.addSubview(vaultClosedImage)
}
```

EDIT: clarify question.

Comment: Did you set the delegate of  `NSAnimationDelegate` to your class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> completion handler does not seem to be recognizing the end of the animation

UIImageView image animation doesn't *have* a "completion handler". It is much more simple-minded than that.

If you want a completion handler, use some sort of animation that *does* have a completion handler.

(In your case, I don't see why you even *need* a completion handler. You know when this animation will end: 1 second from now. So just set an NSTimer to call you back then.)

Comment: And my answer has already answered that. Use a different kind of animation.

Comment: Thank you Matt, you make an excellent and obvious point about the timer.